# Cordova Android plugin send multiple callbacks (progress)

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am writing a custom plugin thats doing some heavy stuff in the code behind. From time to time I want to send a progress update so that I can display it in Ionic. I couldn't find the appropriate method in CallbackContext. Sending success callback is only possible once. How can I achieve sending progress callbacks?

```
private void doHeavyStuff(final CallbackContext callbackContext){

    something.execute(new ResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) { 
                callbackContext.success(message); //what else ?
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                callbackContext.error(message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                callbackContext.success(message);
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `setKeepCallback()` to stop the callback instance being removed on calling, allowing it to be called multiple times:

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if(action.equals("doHeavyStuff"){
        // Start doing async heavy stuff...

        // Preserve callback
        PluginResult pluginResult = new  PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT); 
        pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
        return true;
    }
}

private void doHeavyStuff(final CallbackContext callbackContext){
  something.execute(new ResponseHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onProgress(String message) { 
          PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, message);
          pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true); // keep callback
          callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
     } 

      @Override
      public void onFailure(String message) {
          callbackContext.error(message);
      }

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(String message) {
          callbackContext.success(message);
      }
  });
}
```